# Como manter dados atualizados em duas tabelas?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Existem duas tabelas que devem ser mantidas atualizadas em bancos diferentes, "usuario" do banco de dados "DB1" e "usuario" do "DB2". Neste caso, seria o campo "password" para ser atualizado.
Tenho uma Trigger de BEFORE UPDATE no banco de dados "BD1" que está funcionando normalmente atualizando dados em DB2. Como mostra abaixo:

```
IF old.`password` <> new.`password` THEN
    UPDATE  DB2.usuario
    SET     DB2.usuario.`password`  = new.`password`
    WHERE   DB2.usuario.login       = new.login;
END IF;
```

Mas se faço a criação da mesma Trigger no "DB2" para atualizar o DB1...

```
IF old.`password` <> new.`password` THEN
    UPDATE  DB1.usuario
    SET     DB1.usuario.`password`  = new.`password`
    WHERE   DB1.usuario.login       = new.login;
END IF;
```

acontece o seguinte erro:

> ERROR 1442: 1442: Can't update table 'usuario' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

O "porque" deste erro eu já sei. Mas daí pergunto para vocês, existe alguma outra maneira de atualizar tanto o DB1 quanto DB2, mantendo dados de "password" iguais?

Comment: Não poderia usar o recurso "replicate do table"? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-table

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que uma trigger dispara a outra , talvez criando um campo "origem" você consiga tratar a questão

```
IF old.`password` <> new.`password` AND new.origem <> 'DB2' THEN
    UPDATE  DB2.usuario
    SET     DB2.usuario.`password`  = new.`password` ,
            DB2.ORIGEM = 'DB1'
    WHERE   DB2.usuario.login       = new.login;
END IF; 


IF old.`password` <> new.`password` AND new.origem <> 'DB1'  THEN
    UPDATE  DB1.usuario
    SET     DB1.usuario.`password`  = new.`password`,
            DB2.ORIGEM = 'DB2'
    WHERE   DB1.usuario.login       = new.login;
END IF;
```

Comment: O problema é que desta forma, o campo "origem" e o campo "password" deverão ser alterados, não ficando de forma automática.

Comment: A ideia é manter as duas triggers mas não permitir que sejam chamadas de formas recurviva, bd1 chama bd2 e morre aí, bd2 chama bd1 e morre aí.